# List of dates from while loop

Tags: sql, datetime, while-loop, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have the following while loop:

```
DECLARE @Date Date

DECLARE @Trucks INT

DECLARE @MaxTrucks INT

SET @Date = DATEADD(mm, -1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) 

SET @Trucks = 0

SET @MaxTrucks = 0

WHILE @Date < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0) 

BEGIN
SET @Trucks = (

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([TruckID]))

FROM TruckAvailability

WHERE CONVERT(Date,PlannedStartDT) <= @Date and CONVERT(Date,PlannedEndDT) >=

 @Date and TotalTicks > 0)

IF @Trucks > @MaxTrucks BEGIN SET @MaxTrucks = @Trucks END

SET @Date = DATEADD(day,1,@Date)

END
```

What I need right now is MaxTrucks per Date. So a column with dates and a column with corresponding MaxTrucks.

Kind regards

Comment: Please add the tag for the dbms you are using

Comment: More often than not, loops can be (and should be) avoided.  Sample data and desired results would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a calendar or dates table for this sort of thing.

For only 152kb in memory, you can have 30 years of dates in a table with this:

```
/* dates table */
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
/* 30 years, 19 used data pages ~152kb in memory, ~264kb on disk */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
    [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
into dbo.Dates
from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
               cross join n as tenK  cross join n as hundredK
order by [Date];
create unique clustered index ix_dbo_Dates_date on dbo.Dates([Date]);
```

Without taking the actual step of creating a table, you can generate an adhoc tables of dates using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with just this:

```
declare @fromdate date = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() )-1, 0);
declare @thrudate date = dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() ), 0));
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
select [Date]
from dates;
```

---

Use either like so:

```
select top 1
    d.Date
  , MaxTrucks = count(distinct(ta.TruckId)) desc
from TruckAvailability ta
  inner join dates d
    on d.Date >= convert(date,ta.PlannedStartDT) 
   and d.Date <= convert(date,ta.PlannedEndDT)
where ta.TotalTicks > 0
group by d.Date
order by count(distinct(ta.TruckId)) desc
```

---

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)